# App crashes with AVAudioSession privateBeginInterruption

Tags: ios, xcode, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I'm testing my app on device (a soundboard) and it crashes with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, I have use Breakpoints and the error came from `[AVAudioSession privateBeginInterruption]`

The crash happens following this pattern:

1. The app is launched, we see the main menu
2. A main menu button is pressed and a soundboard view is loaded (push), some buttons are pressed here and sounds are played.
3. Return to main menu (`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`)
4. App enters background
5. When app enters foreground and the menu button of the soundboard is pressed the app crashes.

I have no idea what is happening here, I have installed CrashLytics and it only said:

[image: app crash]

Maybe the audio session gets released from memory and the app tries to access to it and fail?

The audio session is initialised in `viewDidLoad`

```
//  Initialize audio session
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];

UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof    (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
```

In `viewDidUnload` I have

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: nil];
```

Any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: Try again with zombies enabled.

Comment: Although I am using iOS 8 with Swift and the delegate property is deprecated - This question helped me fix my EXC BAD ACCESS problem. I  have forgotten to remove the delegates of the audio recorder which crashed my application with EXC BAD ACCESS error that made it really hard to identify the problem. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The crash happens because you had set the delegate of session to your controller in this line

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
```

but didn't implemented the required delegate method (interruption one)

either remove the delegate setting line or implement the delegate method to solve crash

Comment: I have removed the delegate setting and the crash is no more. Thank you!